# Figure out return type of a functor C++11\Boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, asynchronous

I am writing own implementation for std::async and come across some difficulties. I have such signature:

```
template<class Fn>
Future<typename std::result_of<Fn>::type> runAsync(const Fn & task);
```

But using this, I got "error C2893: Failed to specialize function template". What is the good way to figure out return type of functor and intialize Future correctly?

Comment: `result_of<Fn()>` or `result_of<Fn(void)>`, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `()`s. You can do either...

`result_of<Fn()>`

or

`result_of<Fn(void)>`